# What was the better method to implement chatbox on mobile nowaday

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, chat, silentpush

I was implementing mobile game with my team. And we have argument that push system may not reliable enough. So we should find third party chat message service or open our own chat server instead of relying on silent push notification

But some still belief that using silent push to chat is the standard nowaday and more reliable than implement our own server

The requirement is just to send chat message to active user's chatbox while the app is open

Are there any concern to consider each method?

How about ios and android system setting?

Will our app receive surely recieve silent push if our app still open?

Are there any chat service that software industry used as standard

Comment: Not only are there four questions in one post here, but all of them are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having a look at [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) it has real time database and an FCM for your chat / push notification needs.